# pgrep for processes which are not associated with a terminal in ubuntu

Tags: grep, process

I would like to find all of the PIDs of processes which are not associated with a terminal.

When I do the ps aux | less command, I see in the TTY field a lot of processes with ? character

I would like to get those processes ID, is there a way to do that with pgrep?

I tried looking at the documentary over here https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1 but it's not very clear...

Comment: I guess this is a variant of [your earlier question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329553/custom-garbage-collector-to-manually-close-a-program)!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with `pgrep`. You can do it with `ps`.

```
ps -e -o pid= -o tty= | awk '$2 == "?" {print $1}'
```